# Spectrum of Lyapunov exponents of a linear system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question**: How to show that the eigenvalues of matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and
$
\mathbf{L} = \log \lim_{t \to \infty} \left((e^{\mathbf{A}t}e^{\mathbf{A^T}t})^{\frac{1}{2t}}\right)
$
have equal real parts?

---

**Motivation**:

Consider a system
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{Ax}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is some constant matrx and $\mathbf{M}(t) := e^{\mathbf{A}t}$ is the evolution operator. The Lyapunov exponents of this system are then given by the eigenvalues of

$$
\mathbf{L} :=
\log \lim_{t \to \infty} \left((\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{M^T}(t))^{\frac{1}{2t}}\right) = 
\log \lim_{t \to \infty} \left((e^{\mathbf{A}t}e^{\mathbf{A^T}t})^{\frac{1}{2t}}\right)
$$

Now, on the other hand, the rate of expansion for a system above is constant and is also given by the real parts of $\mathbf{A}$'s eigenvalues. Therefore, eigenvalues of $\mathbf{L}$ are equal to real parts of eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$. I have checked it numerically and it also makes sense intuitively, but I don't see why, technically, the relation holds.

Comment: Are you learning [*Oseledec’s Multiplicative Ergodic Theorem*](http://math.ucr.edu/~kelliher/Geometry/LectureNotes.pdf), which shows a proof. Maybe [*Section 7.3*](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/Chaos_Course/Lesson7/Lyapunov.pdf) is easier to read first? Not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, section 7.3 is actually what caused the question. From what you've said, apparently the proof is given in the depths of the Oseledec's theorem. The relation just looked so simple, so I thought maybe there's a relatively easy proof, like the one for symmetric $A$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your matrix is square.
$$ \log \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} (M(t) M(t)^T)^{ \frac{1}{2t}} = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \log (M(t) M(t)^T)^{ \frac{1}{2t}} =  \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2t} \log (M(t) M(t)^T) $$
since the logarithm is continuous. Now with $M(t) = e^{At}$, you get
$$   \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2t} \log (M(t) M(t)^T) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2t} \log (e^{At}e^{A^Tt}) =  \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2t}(A + A^T)t$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$$
Here you need to show that $A$ ant $A^T$ commute.
Now suppose $\lambda = a+ ib$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$. Then 
$$(A + A^T)v = (\lambda + \bar{\lambda} )v = 2a v $$

Comment: I tried to go this way, but the problem is that $A$ and $A^T$ don't commute in general case. The relation, however, holds for for the general case too, and that's what is mystery for me

Comment: Yes, that is true, it only works for normal matrices. I didnt think about that.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem of Lyapunov ensures that the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of the matrix $\textbf{A}\in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ satisfy $Re(\lambda_i)<0$ if and only if, for any given symmetric positive definite matrix $\textbf{P}$, there exists a unique positive definite symmetric matrix $Q$ satisfying the Lyapunov equation:
$$Q\textbf{A}+\textbf{A}Q=-\textbf{P}$$

In other words your question points directly to the *stability* theorem itself. If I understood your question correctly, I believe the answer points to the Lyapunov theorem itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see right away how to apply this theorem to answer my question. The thing is that first two lines of my question hold for general matrices, without any context. So I wanted to see why exactly is that true, without attaching any stability meaning to it

Comment: Yes understand, but isnt it fact that the eigenvalues you look at are identical because the Lyapunov theorem holds? Disregard for an instance distinguishing between stbale and unstable (signs of eigenvalues), the theorem in first instance installs a relation between the (1) two matrices you mention and (2) exactly with regard to their eigenvalues and (3) more specific on their real part and (4) last but not least of course on the signs. So it gives what you demand for in (1) to (3).

Comment: concerning (1) I can't see where does limit of the logarithm of $MM^T$ appear in this equation. I believe that the relation in question has more to do with the ergodic theorem, because the matrix L appears in the definition in the exact same form as in the question. Sorry if I miss something obvious.

Comment: Intuitively as brought above I do believe that this you require is identical with the Lyapunov Theorem (so the answer above is intuitive) which is found due its limits appropriateness by Oseledec’s theorem and in all details of calculations. However what I can not calculatorily bridge here is the complete Singular Valued Decomposition...